# angularjs ng-repeat can't handle with compiled sub element when item is removed from collection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use create a TAB control

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" ng-show="panes.length > 0">
  <li ng-repeat="pane in panes track by $index" ng-class="{active:pane.selected}">
    <a href="#" ng-click="select(pane)">
      {{pane.title}}<i class="fa fa-close" ng-click="close(pane)" style="margin:0px -8px 0px 15px" ></i>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <ch-pane ng-repeat="pane in panes track by $index" ng-show="pane.selected">
  </ch-pane>
</div>
```

template of ch-pane

```
<div class="tab-pane" style="margin-top:10px">
```

just a placeholder，the directive code is

```
directive('chPane', function($compile) {
return {
  restrict: "E",
  templateUrl: 'chassis/template/tab_pane.html',
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    angular.element(element.children()[0]).append($compile(scope.pane.directive)(scope));
  },
};
})
```

In link function, when a new ch-pane is created, a compiled element which is another customized directive is appended to ch-pane's div

The code works ok when add item to panes collection. But when removing item from panes collection, it failed. 
The situation is: (each item is a Tab)
1. add item A to panes, its ch-pane append a compiled element A1
2. add item B to panes, its ch-pane append a compiled element B1
3. add item C to panes, its ch-pane append a compiled element C1
4. remove A from panes, the result is Tab B display A1 and Tab C display B1

Comment: Can't see any issue from code. Can you make a short demo on jsfiddle/jsbin?

Comment: sorry, I am new js dev and I am setting the environment on jsbin

Comment: https://jsbin.com/wanumi/edit?html,js
here is the link. the reproduce steps are:
1. click item 1
2. click sub item 1
3. click sub item 2
4. click close on tab of sub item 1 (tab title = content commodity)
you will see 'I am content commodity content pane p' is under tab 'content 2 pane'

Comment: Fixed by removing `track by $index` from all `ng-repeat`, probably it has something to do with the `$index` changed during removal of element

Comment: COOL!!! thanks a lot @Icycool